# how to get total number of a variable in each row

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like below name sp

```
Join      p1     sp1       p2      sp2     p3      sp3
  1          0        0           0         0        0          0
   2          1        pine     0         0       1         Aspen
   3           2        pine     0        0       0          0
```

And the dataframe continues with 100 rows where p1 is the number of species indicated by column sp1 and so on.
Now I want to create a new variable pine which counts the total number of tree species
pine in each row (join)

Answer (score 0):

A simple `apply` by row will do it. I subset the data.frame, using `grep` to get the columns that start with `"sp"`.

```
pine <- apply(sp[grep("^sp", names(sp))], 1, function(x) sum(x == "pine"))
pine
#[1] 0 1 1
```

**Data.**

```
sp <- 
structure(list(Join = 1:3, p1 = 0:2, sp1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("0", "pine"), class = "factor"), p2 = c(0L, 0L, 
0L), sp2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), p3 = c(0L, 1L, 0L), sp3 = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "Aspen"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: I used this argument and I only get 0,1 value for the whole dataset.

Comment: @MostarinBinteAhmed I don't see anything wrong with the code above, in the dataset that you posted those results are right, there is 0 or 1 columns `sp` equal to `"pine"` per row.

Comment: in the real dataset I have 1000 row and number of pine in some rows more than 0,1. when I applied the code for the whole dataset I only get 01 for all row which is not same in reality

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your data in long format to perform calculation. Once in data is in long format, `fuzzyjoin::regex_inner_join` will allow joining data for paired values (e.g. `p1 vs sp1`).

An option using `tidyverse` can be as:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fuzzyjoin)         

#To calculate count of Species per row for different type

df %>% gather(Species, value, -Join) %>% 
  mutate(Join = as.character(Join))  %>% {
    regex_inner_join(filter(., grepl("^s",Species)),
              filter(.,grepl("^p",Species)),
              by = c("Join", "Species"))
} %>%
  filter(value.x != "0") %>%
  group_by(Join.x, value.x) %>%
  summarise(count = sum(as.numeric(value.y))) %>% as.data.frame()

#   Join.x value.x count
# 1      2   Aspen     1
# 2      2    pine     1
# 3      3    pine     2

#To calculate count of Species per row 
df %>% gather(Species, value, -Join) %>% 
  mutate(Join = as.character(Join))  %>% {
    regex_inner_join(filter(., grepl("^s",Species)),
              filter(.,grepl("^p",Species)),
              by = c("Join", "Species"))
} %>%
group_by(Join.x) %>%
summarise(count = sum(as.numeric(value.y))) %>% as.data.frame()

#   Join.x count
# 1      1     0
# 2      2     2
# 3      3     2
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"Join      p1     sp1       p2      sp2     p3      sp3
1          0        0           0         0        0          0
2          1        pine     0         0       1         Aspen
3           2        pine     0        0       0          0",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: May be I could not make the problem clear. p1 is the number of occurance for the sp1 and same for p2, sp2 and so on. I want to know how many pine occurs in each row  (join). like in row-2, there is 1 pine and how can I know this for each row